# How can I gate features at compile time?

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile

I have a C++ application I'm developing. I want to release a free version and a paid version, with the production version adding features on top of the existing free version.

What's the best way to compile features depending on the release type? Ideally I would pass a flag to CMake so while building the binary it would also include any code I need in the production version.

Comment: `#if(n)def` macroing?

Comment: The usual is for the code to *always* be there, but check for some kind of validation before enabling the features of the extra "production version" code.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg That's why cracks work.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz True, and having one "production version" is why piracy works. :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - I do that with my desktop shareware. As  Bartek Banachewicz said, cracks.

Comment: If people want to use your software without paying for it, they will, there's no way to stop it. Either they "crack" a licensed copy, or they copy a fully enabled program, it doesn't matter in the end. So I think it comes to this: Which is easiest for ***you***!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You answered your question yourself :) Pass a flag to your compiler and in your code gate the features with:

```
#ifdef YOUR_FLAG
//your extra logic
#elif
//in case YOUR_FLAG is not defined
#endif
```

I used exactly the same approach in a game I developed - in free version ads are enabled and in paid version that code gets excluded by preprocessor.

Also you can use run-time checks in case it's more appropriate for some specific task, but as it's mentioned in comments to the question - code is there and tampering with memory (flipping your flag) will possible allow to gain access to restricted features.

Comment: Problem is, this becomes hard to manage if you want to disable features across a number of components.

Comment: It does make the code less manageable, but that issue can and should be addressed by proper use of good OOP practices. Just as an example: switch to composition and define an interface that your switchable functionality requires, create two classes, implementing this interface (pure virtual class or any other flavour of "interface" construct you like) (one with restricted functionality, another without limitations)  and then in #ifdef block you just instantiate one of those two interface implementations. Good OOP is king and design-patterns are his loyal knights :)

Answer (score 0):

You add them as licensed plugins.

That is:

1. Keep the code seperate. Heck, you can even license the "free" code as open-source and still keep your business model.
2. Make them phone home or verify some crypt key so that you know said person is licensed.
3. Make sure the rest of the code can live with its paid for guts removed. Comfort if necessary.